# How to create short time alert message in Laravel after submitting a form?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

This is custom alert component to include on every page.
I tried it using session-flash, but it remains on page before and also after showing message.
How to trigger and show it only after submitting form for short time.
**using Laravel**

```
@section('alert-section')
   <div >
        <div class="alert alert-{{$color}}" role="alert" style="height: 36x; line-height:36px; padding:4px 20px;">
        <h5>{{$message}}</h5>
        </div>
    </div>
@endsection
```

session flash remains until next page reload, Is there any way to remove it after some seconds.

```
@if(isset($message))
    <x-alert color="success" message="Data has been updated successfully!" />
@endif
```

This code triggers the message after submitting form, but how to remove it after some seconds

Comment: Why don't you do it by javascript setTimeout function? You can add some styling like hide after a few seconds.

Comment: Your alert will only disappear after a reload of the page, also you need to use a if when there is no message to show

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can refer to this sample code for setTimeout for hiding an element.

```
setTimeout(() => {
  const box = document.getElementById('box');

  // ️ removes element from DOM
  box.style.display = 'none';

  // ️ hides element (still takes up space on the page)
  // box.style.visibility = 'hidden';
}, 1000); // ️ time in milliseconds
```

Or you can try this way with jQuery:

```
setTimeout(function() {
    $('.alert').fadeOut('fast');
}, 1000); // ️ time in milliseconds
```